# Tutorial for IP-based Virtual Hosting

Tags: ssl, vps

I want to host multiple SSL websites on my virtual private server.  I was told that in order to achieve this, I need to do IP-based virtual hosting.  If this is the case, can someone recommend a newb guide on how to set this up?

I am using Ubuntu 9.10, apache 2, and php 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do IP based virtual hosting. You just need to make sure each VirtualHost that your are running an SSL site on is bound to a unique IP.

Comment: Thank you, I posted a follow up question asking how to bind unique IP here http://serverfault.com/questions/109766/ssl-site-not-using-the-correct-ip-in-apache-and-ubuntu