# How to use 2 SSL Certificate on same IP on ubuntu apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

Is there a way to do it without using SNI Mod Apache?

I tried many thing but no 1 them worked for me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use different ports for each virtual host.

You simply cannot have two certs on a single address+port without SNI support.

Comment: default SSL port is 443, u mean that i should use another port to this second domain? i.e: 442 port?

Comment: I found http://serverfault.com/questions/110002/multiple-ssl-websites-on-the-same-apache-server, this guy seem fixed it. but i don't understand it.

Comment: Yes you can use a different port number.  442, would work, if it isn't used by anything else on your system.  The guy in the other question had a unique IP per site.

Comment: hum yes but it look like local IP , isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Many SSL providers offer multi-domain SSL certificates, you may want to look in to these. These allow you to have a simple Apache configuration, but multiple sites on one HTTPS IP address. These are not ideal for sites requiring separation, but in this case an isolated server/VM may make more sense.